# I have redirected stdout and stderr, why do I still get some output?

Tags: bash, shell

I did something like the following in a bash terminal

```
( some_command ) >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Yet I still got something printed. Here `some_command` runs a command-line program private to my organization. How did the sub-shell manage to print something to the console while I redirected both `STDOUT` and `STDERR`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is that the program is particularly rude and is printing to the [controlling terminal](http://www.lindevdoc.org/wiki/Controlling_terminal) *directly*, which would circumvent all redirecting.

For example:

```
$ ( echo "can't touch this" > /dev/tty ) >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
can't touch this
```

([`/dev/tty`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty) refers to the current process's controlling terminal.)

Comment: Not necessarily rude; sometimes it's a necessity (think interactive password prompts, for example).